# Get-MgUser works well when run in interactive Powershell, but not in Task Scheduler

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, windows-task-scheduler

I have an issue which I am unable to understand. I have a PowerShell script which connects to MS Graph (`Microsoft.Graph.Users` module pre-loaded), and extracts some Azure AD user properties, then saves them in a CSV file (using `Set-Content`).

When I run the script in interactive mode, it works very well. However, if the script is configured in a Task Scheduler task, `Get-MgUser` returns empty value.

The task is configured to run "whether user is logged on or not" and runs under the same account I use in Interactive mode (When running the task, use the following user account:[user]).

I am not able to understand why it returns empty value in task scheduler.

I am out of ideas on what to test. Something I miss on why it returns empty value, instead of users properties.

Comment: Please show us the code, and explain how you determined that `Get-MgUser` returned an empty value (as opposed to throwing an error)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today and was already crying.
Then I figured out that the command that queries Graph was....in another PS tab :)